# organizing the dataset and sorting the edited data

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv',
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# I did wrong.
df11 <- aggregate(df$confirmed, by=list(df$countryName) subset(df,df$confirmed < df$recovered) , FUN 
== "max"))
```

within countries
Find the dates when the number of recovered has passed confirmation.

as output ;

```
day              countryName        confirmed     recovered 
2020/04/10         Spain              1500          1550
2020/01/19         italy              862            900
...
```

data are examples. are not real values.

Comment: `FUN=max` (single `=`). And you're missing a comma before `subset`

Comment: There is no row in the data where `recovered` is greater than `confirmed`. `subset(df, recovered > confirmed)` .  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No country has had more recovered than cases (as of today). This is confirmed with:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(day=as.Date(day)) %>%
  group_by(countryName) %>%
  filter(confirmed<recovered) %>%
  top_n(1, wt=day)

# A tibble: 0 x 9
```

Now let's suppose that tomorrow, all cases in the US miraculously recover and no new cases occur. ;)

```
tomorrow <- read.table(text="
             day countryCode   countryName   region lat lon confirmed recovered death
21379 2020/05/09          US United States Americas  38 -97   1187233   1187234 68566", header=TRUE)
```

Let's add this row to the data and run the code again:

```
df2 <- rbind(df, tomorrow)
df2 %>%
  mutate(day=as.Date(day)) %>%
  group_by(countryName) %>%
  filter(confirmed<recovered) %>%
  top_n(1, wt=day)

#  A tibble: 1 x 9
#  Groups:   countryName [1]
#   day        countryCode countryName   region     lat   lon confirmed recovered death
#   <date>     <chr>       <chr>         <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>     <int>     <int> <int>
# 1 2020-05-09 US          United States Americas    38   -97   1187233   1187234 68566
```

Comment: Of course, no country will _ever_ have more recovered than confirmed cases since the recovered group are a subset of the confirmed cases. At best the number of recovered can equal the number of confirmed cases but only if the country reported no deaths.